# Webception / webdriver / ftp

Tags: php, selenium, ftp, webdriver, codeception

I use Codeception with webdriver and use command line to start tests. I try to use webception to show it on a web-application for my colleagues so I deployed webception on my FTP but i have problems with piloting selenium. I didnt succeed to run the test from my ftp with webcept.

```
[WebDriverCurlException]
Curl error thrown for http POST to http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session with params:    {"desiredCapabilities":{"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"accept","browserName":"firefox"}}
couldn't connect to host
```

Here is my acceptance.suit.yml :

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
enabled:
    #- PhpBrowser
    - WebHelper
    - REST
    - WebDriver

config:
    REST:
        url: 'http://theAddress/'
        timeout: 90
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://theAddress/'
        curl:
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION: true                
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://theAddress/'
        browser: firefox         
        capabilities:
            unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

Any suggestions will be welcome. thank you

Comment: no I would like to, but didnt have lot of time on it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Selenium manually. Download Selenium Server here [Selenium Downloads](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) , then in the command line, navigate  to the folder where the file has been downloaded and type:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-W.XY.Z.jar
```

Now, Selenium should be running on the 4444 port. After that, try to run your test again.